# Does RewriteEngine On enable for all subsequent vhosts

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

If I have in my conf.d Apache directory 001_vhost.conf 002_vhost.conf ... etc, does Putting RewriteEngine On in 004_vhost.conf enable the Rewrite Engine for 005 006 007 008 etc vhosts, but not those that came before in the virtual host load order?  This is assuming I don't have that directive anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends where you have it in the configs (i.e. which section, not which file).
For example, if you have `RewriteEngine on` within your VirtuaHost section, that will apply to that host only.
If you put it in the global config, that will apply to the main host (not your virtual hosts which need to be enabled individually).

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine

Comment: From the docs "Note that rewrite configurations are not inherited by virtual hosts. This means that you need to have a RewriteEngine on directive for each virtual host in which you wish to use rewrite rules."  That is what I wanted to know, I should have checked there first, thanks.